# Null Pointer Exception - Eclipse remote Hadoop

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hdfs

I have been seaching for days now, Please HELP

I have a nullpointerexception when executing a simple Wordcount for Hadoop (I have installed a cluster of VMs Ubuntu 14 of hadoop and run eclipse LOCALY)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:833)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:76)
```

This is my code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
//import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class WordCount {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);

    System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hduser");
    // specify output types
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hduser");
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://10.99.99.2:54310/user/hduser");
    //log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop = DEBUG
    conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "10.99.99.2:54311");




    // specify input and output dirs
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path("input"));  //hdfs://10.99.99.2:54310/user/hduser/input/Good.txt
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("output"));  

    // specify a mapper
    conf.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);

    // specify a reducer
    conf.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(WordCountReducer.class);



    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);


    // CREATE FILE AND PRINT PATH TO CHECK IS EVERYTHING IS OK
    fs.createNewFile(new Path("/user/hduser/test"));

    FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/user/hduser"));
    for(int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
        System.out.println(status[i].getPath());

    }


    // READ TXT TO BE SURE THERE IS NOT PERMISSION PROBLEM
    Path pt= new Path("hdfs://10.99.99.2:54310/user/hduser/input/Good.txt");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
    String line;
    line=br.readLine();
    while (line != null){
            System.out.println(line);
            line=br.readLine();  }

    JobClient client = new JobClient(conf);
    client.setConf(conf);


    try {
      JobClient.runJob(conf);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*The code looks fine! Please make sure you are giving an accurate command to reply the JAR file and also you can make some tests and debug them to understand where the null pointer Exception is coming from.*

Comment: Dear Rachit, what do you mean by "accurate command to reply the JAR file" ?

Comment: I meant Deploy*. I would suggest to program some Tests for the code and debug them with some input.